# Perl RegEx on unknown format

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I am trying to replace some decoded characters (for example like \x{2013},\u{38} etc.) with spaces. Following is the regex which I used. But I receive `Wide character` error or some characters are still not decoded properly in print message. I think it is not matching the expression and I tried different ways. I want all of those decoded characters with some space or - . Please find my non working code below:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $sai = qq(Asdf \\u2013abc<br />jkl-abcd<br /><div>!\\"\\u00A3$%^&amp;*()-_     =+</div><div>{</div><div>}</div><div>[</div><div>]</div><div>: ; @ \' # ~*,,</div><div>? &gt; &lt; . , / | \\\\ ` /* - + . &nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;12345</div><div>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div><ul><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-026f68485\\">\\u00FC<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>Abcd</li><ul><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-026f68485\\">v<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>Abcd</li><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-026f68485\\">v<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>Jkl</li><ul><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0a7a49fef\\">\\u00B7<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>Asdf</li></ul><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-026f68485\\">\\u00A7<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>test</li></ul></ul><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div><ul><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-026f68485\\">\\u00D8<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>Dfgst</li><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-026f68485\\">\\u00D8<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>Sdrgdg</li><ul><li><span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0a7a49fef\\">\\u00B7<span obj=\\"venit-rte-obj-0196185f4\\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>Abcd</li></ul></ul>Testing \\u2013 code</div> \x{2013};\x{2013}abcjkl-abcd!\"\x{a3} \$%^&*()-_=+{}[]: ;\@ ' # ~*,,? >  AbcdTesting \x{2013} code670123456789 \x{fc} Abcdv Abcdv Jkl\x{b7} Asdfs\x{a7} test \x{d8} Dfgst\x{d8} Sdrgdg\x{b7});

    for ($sai)
   {

     s/[^\p{ASCII}]//g;
     s/\\u[0-9]+/-/g;
     s/\\x[a-z0-9]/-/g;

   }

   print $sai;
```

now only x{d8} and etc.. were not disappearing

Comment: Add [`use utf8;`](https://ideone.com/Wc9XRz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `qq` (double-quote) operator supports backslash sequences like `\x{2013}`, so this:

```
my $process = qq(\x{2013});
```

declares `$process` and initializes it to a string containing a single [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (U+2013).

This:

```
$process =~ s/\\x\{[0-9]+\}//sg ;
```

removes any sequences like `\x{2013}` from `$process`; but it doesn't include any such sequences, all it contains is a single en dash.

If your goal is to strip out any wide characters (characters above U+007F), you can write:

```
$process =~ s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g;
```

Comment: HI tried first answer and it works.second answer is also best i think but didn't try yet.

Comment: I will put my whole program here.as i still have issues with few special characters

Comment: Hi ruakh,  s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g; is removing my entire string :( .can you please my latest updated code

Comment: Your suggestion is equivalent to the `s/[^\p{ASCII}]//g` they did use

Comment: @Perl, no, it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `\x{2013}` isn't a piece of text - it's a unicode character. You're escaping it in your regex, so the regex isn't matching.

This will work for that specific character:

```
my $process = qq(\x{2013});
$process =~ s/\x{2013}//sg ;
print $process;
```

But if you want to more generally remove unicode characters from a string:

```
my $process = qq(\x{2013});
$process =~ s/[^\w\s\d]+//g ;
print $process;
```

Edit: From comments - if you just want to remove 'non ASCII - it's worth looking at [`perlrecharclass`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html)

```
$process =~ s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g;
```

Comment: HI Sobrique , can you please find my updated code and provide me best solution please? as its an important thing for me to do. thank you

Comment: what does ^\w mean it is replacing my other \\"verit etc.. stuff aswell

Comment: `[^\w\s\d]` means "not word, whitespace or digit" - it's an exclude pattern. To work with it,all you'd need is adding all the characters you want to keep.

Comment: OH OK i GOT IT. SO I WANT ALL ASCII AND WANT TO AVOID ALL NON-ASCII.HOW CAN I WRITE THAT?

Comment: Hi Thank you for that even if i use that I still see \u2013 stuff in output :(

Comment: I am trying to get rid of \x{b7} which is not going and all others went of by doing following code , s/[^\p{ASCII}]//g;
s/\\u[0-9]+/-/g;
s/\\x[a-z0-9]/-/g;

Comment: This works: `my $sai = qq(Asdf \x{b7}); $sai =~ s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/;  print $sai;` - I think you're still getting mixed up by the double-backslashes again.

Comment: Thank you.You are right when i replace non-ascii with space it is mixed up with smething else so replacing with - worked . Also, I use 4 following to fix this issue 1.s/[^\p{ASCII}]/-/g;
2.s/\\u[0-9]+/-/g;
3.s/\\x[a-z0-9]/-/g;
4.s/[^\x00-\x7F]/-/g;